# Получить директорию windows удалённого компьютера

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Я нашёл только способ через регистр, но может есть какие - нибудь готовые функции для этого, вроде `GetWindowsDirectory`? У меня в сети есть несколько компов, как я могу узнать на каком диске установлена у них винда, C:\Windows или D:\Windows, используя для этого язык С++? Другими словами: аналог GetWindowsDirectory с возможность указать имя компьютера

Comment: @МишаковМаксим не надо уточнять вопрос в комментариях, они не для этого. Воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править".

Comment: можно воспользоваться пакетом утилит от [Sysinternals](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysinternals), в часности я веду речь об утилите [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), при использовании которой можно получить интересующую вас информацию(запустив на удаленном пк cmd и получить вывод команды `echo %windir%`)

Comment: Есть серьезные подозрения, что стартующая Windows (начиная с семерки, кажется) называет системный диск C: , даже если это не  первый раздел на диске. Даже не знаю, есть ли способ сделать иначе при установке Винды.

Comment: Так в постановке задачи Вы не указали полностью её условия. Через какой интерфейс нужно обращаться к удаленному компьютеру?